# Flutter crashing on failed PlatformAssetBundle

Tags: flutter, dart

Running my app I get a crash, but stack trace doesn't go deep enough because of an Async call? I cannot figure out what is trying to grab an image?

Below is the assets part of my pubspec.yaml file

```
assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

Using VSCode and it shows any images I reference or if I mouse over the reference it shows the images.

```
@protected
  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(AssetBundleImageKey key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
    ByteData data;
    // Hot reload/restart could change whether an asset bundle or key in a
    // bundle are available, or if it is a network backed bundle.
    try {
      data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);
    } on FlutterError {
      PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.evict(key);
      rethrow;  <---- crashes here
    }
```

I am not grabbing any external images (URL) in my code. I added Google Maps SDK so maybe its something it is trying to grab? But not sure why no stack trace?

[image]

VSCode see the images before I send it to the iOS simulator. These are the images that it cannot find. It finds all other images referenced in the file.

[image: VScode see images]

Answer (score 0):

> Below is the assets part of my pubspec.yaml file
>
> ```
> assets:
>     - assets/
>     - assets/images/
> ```

Try to follow the indentation of the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets).

Here is an example:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

If the error still exist, try to follow the workaround here:

> It worked for me:
>
> 1. Set only full path to asset in pubspec.yaml
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> assets:
>     - assets/files/asset.txt
>     - assets/images/icons/myicon.png
> ```
>
> Whole folder not worked for me `- assets/`
>
> 2. Add `./` to the beginning of your asset path when you loading it
>
> e.g. `rootBundle.loadString('./assets/path/to your/asset.txt`
>
> 3. `flutter clean`

Also, as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17870#issuecomment-415109710), using `flutter clean` is a good idea if there are some weird behavior from your app.